# What is the purpose of a trailing minus sign?

Tags: finance

I cashier at a grocery store and the POS system we use (SurePOS by IBM/Toshiba) uses trailing minus signs for all of its representations of negative numbers.

Examples:

- Coupon being rung up:

`MC    SCANNED COUPON    1.50-`

- Change due when a check is written for $20 over the amount:

`BALANCE: 20.00-`

What is the reason for the trailing minus sign, why not `-1.50` instead?

Comment: Perhaps you should ask the POS system manufacturer?

Comment: It's not specific to the system though, I have seen it in other places too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that this allows for a quick scan down the right-hand column to see which items are negative. All minus signs will be in the same column. If the minus signs are on the left-hand side, then they won't necessarily line up.

Compare:

> `A     15.00-`
>
> `B   1255.50`
>
> `C      0.10-`
>
> `D    175.00-`

to

> `A    -15.00`
>
> `B   1255.50`
>
> `C     -0.10`
>
> `D   -175.00`

Comment: I figured it was something like that, thanks!